# The additive groups $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 1$ are all isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory

> **Question:** How to show that the additive groups $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 1$ are all isomorphic (as abstract groups).

I've read this statement in the comments of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/63636/90299) mathoverflow question. We can certainly find set theoretic bijections $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ because both sets have the same cardinality, but how do we ensure that it respects addition?

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25375/ac-in-group-isomorphism-between-r-and-r2) may be of interest(?)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the axiom of choice.

As a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the same dimension as $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore you can find a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, and this map gives an isomorphism of abelian groups.

Comment: Are you saying that $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}^n=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $n\geq 1$?

Comment: @Paul: Yes. You can show $\dim_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R} = \operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})$, and then $\dim_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}^n = \operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R}) \times\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})\times \cdots \times \operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})$ ( $n$ times) $=  \operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: How do you multiply cardinalities? Do you rather mean $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}^n=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Product of cardinals is defined in the obvious way: $\alpha\beta$ is the cardinal of the cartesian product, which, as soon as at least one is infinite (and the other nonzero), equals $\max(\alpha,\beta)$.