# Why is $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}^n=\operatorname{card}\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\geq1$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

> **Question:** How to show that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, when viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

This is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912083/365704). This dimension is clearly infinite, but why is it precisely the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For any infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space $V$ and for any $n ≥ 1$, we have $\dim_k(V^n) = \dim_k(V)$.

Comment: This is  true also for vector spaces with a countable basis.